# Desenvolvimento C# Mobile precisa de Mac?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, mobile, xamarin

Estava pesquisando sobre ferramentas para desenvolvimento mobile (iOS, Android) e me deparei com o Xamarin.

Achei interessante a proposta, ainda mais por trabalhar em conjunto com o Visual Studio. Fiz o download e configurei, porém, apesar de estar com uma maquina intermediaria (i3, 6GB de RAM) tive um tempo absurdo para executar aplicativos testes distribuídos como exemplo pelo Xamarin, além do aplicativo executar com lag extremo no meu celular emulado.

Pesquisei e me deparei com a informação de que para desenvolver para iOS, preciso de um mac os sendo executado em minha maquina, seja ela virtual ou um mac. Porém, se possuo lag em uma maquina regular, imagino em uma maquina virtual.

Existe algum modo de otimizar a performance de emulação? Não existe meios de trabalhar com o Xamarin para iOS sem rodar mac os?

Existe algum outro programa que trabalhe em conjunto com o Visual Studio para desenvolvimento mobile ou até mesmo que seja otimizado para C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Microsoft além de abrir o .NET comprou a Xamarin e [preparou o Visual Studio para atender o desenvolvimento nas diversas plataformas](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx). Já nesta versão tem até emulador para Android. E incluiu o Xamarin até mesmo na versão [Community](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101). Há uma espécie de emulador para iOS no Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Estou respondendo mais para não ficar sem resposta. Fique de olho nos acontecimentos, quem sabe o problema é resolvido com a nova postura. Mas não sei se há alguma coisa que possa de fato eliminar a necessidade do Mac, isto parece ser uma limitação da plataforma.

A [Xamarin tem um serviço](https://appcenter.ms/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que ajuda nisto. Me parece ser a solução mais viável. Se não usar um serviço assim, precisa de um Mac para não incorrer em violação dos termos da Apple. Isto vale para qualquer tecnologia de desenvolvimento para iOS.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).