# Desenvolver para várias plataformas usando C# e Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Para não ter que aprender várias tecnologias para desenvolver para as várias plataformas móveis, queria usar apenas C#.

No entanto tenho algumas dúvidas, nomeadamente:

1. O Xamarin Studio é gratuito?
2. Com o mesmo código, a aplicação gerada corre nas três plataformas?
3. Possuo um Mac. Se eu tiver um projeto no Mac que rodo nas três plataformas, posso abrir esse projeto em um PC Windows? Posso editar normalmente, fazer testes no Android e ele me garante que as alterações funcionarão no iOS? O projecto continuará a funcionar quando for aberto novamente no Mac?
4. Relativamente à interface gráfica. Como são feitas? Apenas uma para todas as plataformas?

Comment: O #1 é bem fácil: https://store.xamarin.com/

Comment: é caro eim...rsrsrs

Comment: Você sabe C++? Se souber, utilizando Qt você pode desenvolver para todas estas plataformas. Também programava C#, mas migrei para Qt quando resolvi começar a aprender mobile. A transição foi bem simples. Desculpe se esta não é uma opção.

Comment: seria uma opção boa, eu gosto de c++, e sempre quis me aprofundar, porem tem pouco conteudo pra mobile.

Comment: @WarLock tem alguma coisa que eu precise melhorar na resposta para responder totalmente o que você perguntou? Me informe que tentarei melhorar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Sim, totalmente gratuito. Mas precisa de uma licença de algum IDE da Microsoft, provavelmente um Visual Studio, até mesmo o Community.
2. Essencialmente [é possível usar o mesmo código para todas as três plataformas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101), mas não quer dizer que não precisa tomar cuidados específicos para garantir que fique tudo bom. Nem quer dizer que seja a melhor solução de UI.

   A parte de *backend* pode ser a mesma e rodar onde bem entender, não depende da plataforma *frontend*. Claro que você precisa fazer de uma forma que não cause problemas para nenhuma plataforma, mas isso é fácil, a comunicação em todas as plataformas pode ser feita da mesma forma e isto é o que importa. Evidentemente que se o *frontend* de cada plataforma, por alguma razão não seguir a mesma arquitetura, vai ter problemas, mas o normal é ser igual.
3. Não tenho experiência, mas não é tão simples assim. Multi-plataforma traz uma impedância natural. Veja [Desenvolvimento C# Mobile precisa de Mac?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101)
4. Com [Xamarin Forms](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin/xamarin-forms?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é possível fazer um código para todas as plataformas.

   A experiência pode ser não a melhor possível em todas elas, principalmente agora que o produto ainda não está totalmente maduro. Mas sempre tem formas de minimizar os problemas que podem aparecer. Mas se decidir não usá-lo terá que fazer um código para cada plataforma seguindo as diretrizes de cada uma. Pode ficar melhor mas dá bem mais trabalho fazer e principalmente manter. Mais detalhes: [Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Xamarin.Forms Shared](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101)

Mas algumas coisas podem mudar agora que o [.NET é *open source*](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-open-source-of-net-core-framework-net-core-distribution-for-linux-osx-and-free-visual-studio-community-edition?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) com [licença MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) e o [Mono vai passar por grande revolução](https://tirania.org/blog/archive/2014/Nov-12.html). [Veja mais](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx) sobre como a Microsoft está comprometida com outras plataformas.

Mudou tudo desde a resposta aqui. Veja [Qual .NET devo utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183229/101) e [Quais as diferenças dos ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275588/101) e ainda [O que devo entender quando dizem ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

1-Não é gratuito.
2-Com o mesmo codigo, podes correr varias plataformas, tirando o codigo que é necessario para comunicar com a API de cada plataforma.
3-Não testei, não te posso dar uma certeza.
4-Para cada plataformas tens de fazer uma interface grafica para cada uma. Uma activity(Android), uma View(IOS) e uma Xaml para windows phone.

Answer (score 2):

Na empresa em que trabalho, usamos o Xamarin. Mesmo que você vá desenvolver em C# é necessário que você tenha um certo conhecimento em Java (a maioria dos exemplos é em java) e desenvolvimento Java Android. Pois o que o Xamarin faz é "encapsular" os códigos java. Você irá as mesmas classes que há no Java android, por exemplo Toast.MakeText(); É uma IDE muito boa, tem os seus problemas, como por exemplo, no último update que fiz, ele não redenrizava o axml então tive que fazer um downgrade no Tools do sdk.

Comment: JcSaint, se incomodaria te me adicionar no skype ou me enviar um email para trocarmos ideia sobre Xamarin? joaquimgoncalvesmagalhaes@hotmail.com - joaquim.m1 (skype). Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre projetos de grande porte.