# Qual .NET devo utilizar?

Tags: .net, winforms

Vou iniciar o desenvolvimento de um programa com C# usando WinForms (Agenda básica com MySQL) e fica minha dúvida qual *framework* utilizar.

Esse programa poderá ser disponibilizado em outros computadores e não sei qual o Windows que poderá estar instalado.

Quais aspectos devo analisar?

Comment: Recomendo que veja a possibilidade de iniciar projetos novos com UWP e não WinForms. UWP é a tecnologia que mais vem recebendo investimentos em suas melhorias, e WinForms está estagnada.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi WinForms está estagnada, entretanto é muito estável e possui muito material disponível para consulta.

Comment: @Murilo sim, é estável por ser muito antiga e ainda em uso, e possui muito material por, igualmente, ser uma tecnologia muito antiga - qto mais tempo de mercado, mais conteúdo terá sido produzido. Porém, já se estagnou, não é mais tendencia - acredito que em breve irá se congitar sua descontinuação. UWP é o presente - nem futuro é mais.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Desculpe a demora pelo feedback. Sim sim, as respostas me ajudaram sobre o assunto. Os links complementaram muito bem o que precisava (muito boa a tabela sobre os frameworks e versões do c#). Obrigada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agora minha resposta é um pouco diferente e deve usar o .NET Core mais novo, ou seja, pelo menos o 3.0 que aceita o uso de WinForms. Vou deixar a resposta original abaixo, mas é isto, vá de .NET Core porque [o .NET Framework morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

---

O que é melhor para você só você pode dizer. Eu prefiro sempre usar o mais atual, no caso é o .NET Framework 4.6.2. Eu tenho uma [pergunta sobre as versões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101) (que por sinal preciso atualizar).

Se fizer tudo direitinho na instalação o .NET Framework necessário para sua aplicação será instalado ou atualizado.

Não importa o que vai usar, não vejo motivos para usar um mais antigo. Mas pode ser que você saiba de algo que eu não sei. Pode decidir que quer usar só o .NET já instalado. Aí tem que ver qual é o computador mais antigo que vai usá-lo e usar na sua aplicação a versão que vem com esse Windows. Eu não recomendo isso. Tem uma [tabela com as versões que vêm junto com o Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Release_history).

Note que existem outras implementações do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). Tem o Mono, tem .NET para outros tipos de dispositivo, tem o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) e até o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). Para WinForms o ideal é usar o .NET Framework "normal".

Além do WinForms pode usar o WPF e o UWP (este último pode ser usado como o .NET Core que não precisa de instalação de nada). Agora todos podem rodar no .NET Core.

Cada um tem suas vantagens e desvantagens. Nenhum é o mais certo. Depende da sua necessidade. Todos eles ainda podem ser usados, mesmo que não tenha evolução, ainda são oficialmente suportados.

Answer (score 3):

Como desenvolvedor(a), o mínimo que você deve saber é o target (**alvo**) para o qual o projeto será construído. Estabeleça você mesmo(a) os requisitos.

O mais óbvio é prover compatibiliadde para as versões mais recentes e com maior número de usuários ao ambiente onde deseja distribuir o aplicativo. De um modo geral, atualmente o alvo pode ser a partir do Windows 7. Se "funciona" sob Windows7, é provável que "funcionará bem" sob Windows 10, por exemplo, dependendo dos recursos que utiliza. Normalmente a IDE que utiliza pede para definir um **alvo** (build target)

Passos básicos na documentação do MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx