# Quais as diferenças dos ".NET"?

Tags: .net, terminologia, .net-core, cross-platform, portabilidade

Dei uma olhada nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183229/qual-net-devo-utilizar), porém não respondeu minha pergunta. Até onde sei, existe o **.NET Framework, .NET Core, ASP.NET, .NET Standart e Mono** mas não sei a diferença deles e não sei qual devo usar para devidos projetos.

Construí uma inteligência artificial em .NET Framework pensando em rodar em outras plataformas, mas fui recomendado recomeçar o projeto inteiramente em .NET Core. Mas, por quê?

Também construí um projeto em .NET Standart pensando em rodar apenas em Windows, mas também fui recomendado recomeçar o projeto em .NET Framework, também não entendi essa diferença.

Para projetos multi-plataforma, o que usar? E se for só para Windows? E se quiser rodar num Android? Sei lá, fazer um jogo para iOS? Um site/aplicativo online profissional? Ou quem sabe um jogo mais complexo para Xbox... Posso usar .NET em tudo isso? Se sim, qual devo usar?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é o .Net Core?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40671/o-que-%C3%A9-o-net-core)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- ASP.NET é só uma parte desses *frameworks* maiores, não faz parte do CLR.
- [.NET Framework morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101), o resto do parágrafo não importa mais ou nem é mais verdade (mais no final da resposta). Só funciona no Windows e já costuma vir instalado nele, e é o único que, no momento, funciona com Windows Forms, WPF e ASP.NET clássico, além de acessar uma série de tecnologias que só faz sentido no Windows. Ele é totalmente suportado, mas reduziu a cadência de melhorias. Tem a infraestrutura completa. Tenta se conformar com .NET Standard.
- .NET Core roda em diversas plataformas, é modular, adequado para rodar em nuvem, *container* e serve bem *backend* e console. Pode rodar bibliotecas para GUI normalmente. Só roda ASP.NET MVC na sua última versão ou o Core dele. Não depende de um *runtime* instalado. Roda até no Xbox. Se conforma com .NET Standard usando truques (na verdade ele passou ser o padrão agora).
- .NET Standar**d** é só uma especificação, é um padrão que as implementações devem seguir para se conformar com ele. Cada implementação escolhe suportar a versão que desejar. Mas andou tem uns truques para se conformar e algumas implementações estão criando só assinaturas para conseguir compilar e se conformar, mas não faz o esperado, provavelmente só lança uma exceção. Ele é útil para balizar o que usa quando pretende usar várias implementações diferentes. Agora ele faz pouco ou nenhum sentido.
- Mono é a implementação independente multiplataforma que hoje é mantida pela Microsoft. Cada vez precisamos menos dele. Conforma-se com .NET Standard, com truques.
- Xamarin, baseado em Mono para rodar no Mac, iOS e Android. Se conforma com .NET Standard, com truques. É mais uma forma de empacotar o Mono que algo diferente.
- .NET Native é parecido com o .NET Core e gera código nativo sem runtime (o executável tem tudo o que precisa).
- Rotor é uma implementação separada criada pela Microsoft para atender os requisitos para que a especificação da plataforma fosse aceita internacionalmente com um padrão formal. Nunca usado em produção.
- .NET Compact Framework é o .NET de forma mais limitada para rodar em antigos celulares e PDAs. Essencialmente desnecessário hoje em dia e acho que podemos considerá-lo obsoleto.
- .NET Micro Framework é uma implementação bem limitada e simples que consome poucos recursos para atender as demandas de dispositivos embarcados de baixa capacidade. Bem pouco usado. Roda com 64KiB e não precisa de sistema operacional.
- TinyCLR OS é uma iniciativa de terceiros para manter o objetivo do .NET MF que parece estar sendo negligenciado pela Microsoft.
- .NET Robotics, até onde eu sei uma variação para atender as demandas de robótica, mas parece abandonado.
- XNA Framework é uma versão do .NET Compact Framework especializado em jogos.
- MonoGame seria o XNA baseado no Mono.
- Unity é baseado em Mono e especializado para jogos e faz sucesso.
- .NET Portable foi uma tentativa de criar uma alternativa GNU ao .NET, mas foi abandonado.
- CrossNet e SharpLang foram tentativas de criar código nativo para o .NET.
- FlingOS e COSMOS e MOSA são sistemas operacionais baseados no .NET adaptado.
- .NET Foundation é só uma fundação (entidade sem fins lucrativos) que detém direitos sobre o .NET promovendo seu uso livre. Não é um *framework*.

Esta lista está longe de querer ser completa. Nem falei das versões usadas em projetos de pesquisa e experimentações da Microsoft e outras adaptações feitas para criar sistemas operacionais.

Trate todos como experimentais ou legados. Em projetos novos deve usar apenas o .NET Core, ou agora (2021 em diante) só chamado de .NET, [só ele será suportado amplamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

[Coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando fala do Mono - "Cada vez precisamos menos dele", o que quer dizer com isso ? o que seria "Com truques" ? um exemplo.

Comment: @samuelrvg o .NET Core, Xamarin e outras implementações cobrem a maior parte do que o Mono faz e a tendência é isso ser ampliado. Truque é criar método *stub* que lança uma exceção dizendo que ele não está implementado. Isso foi uma das maiores atrocidades que já vi no .NET. Alguns casos até implementam alguma coisa, mas não da maneira como deveria, então a conformidade é só com a assinatura.

Comment: @Maniero Tem um novo. O que é o [bflat](https://github.com/bflattened/bflat)?

Comment: @CypherPotato não sei se ele tem mérito pra entrar nessa lista, mas fica seu comentário.