# Usar DLL do .NET Framework no .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, .net-core

Uma DLL em C# compilada em .NET 4.6 pode ser importada por um programa em .NET Core em Linux?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Em princípio, sim. O formato das DLLs do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), ou mais comumente chamado .NET (apesar de ser tecnicamente um erro), é universal e funciona em qualquer ambiente preparado para seu uso. isto inclui pegar algo do .NET Framework e usar no [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Só haveria alguma diferença para o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que tem um formato nativo.

Isso não quer dizer que tudo funcionará. O que faz parte do [.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) funcionará, já o que é específico de uma implementação não funcionará. Você não poderá usar coisas específicas para o Windows. Mesmo o .NET Core 3.0 suportando [WinForms](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) e [WPF](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf) não significa que ele rodará no Linux, a não ser que alguém os porte para este sistema operacional, o que não é simples, principalmente no WPF.

Então o formato do executável não é problema, mas nem todo código é universal.

Veja mais em [Quais as diferenças dos ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275588/101).