# Como funciona o desenvolvimento para Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

- Se eu quiser criar um app no Xamarin para Ios, sou obrigado a ter um Mac?
- O Xamarin cria uma pasta no projeto Android e Ios, e qual seria a pasta pra Windows Phone?
- Xamarin cria o código nativo das demais plataformas em tempo real?

Comment: O desenvolvimento não é "para Xamarin". O desenvolvimento é no Xamarin para multiplataformas.

Answer (score 5):

> Se eu quiser criar um app no Xamarin para IOS, sou obrigado a ter um MAC?

Já foi respondido em [Desenvolvimento C# Mobile precisa de Mac?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101), não vou repetir aqui.

> O Xamarin cria uma pasta no projeto Droid e IOS, e qual seria a pasta pra Windows Phone?

Não tem relevância mais. WP morreu.

> Xamarin Cria o código nativo das demais plataformas em tempo real?

Ele cria código nativo para todas suas plataformas suportadas, algumas delas até exigem isso. Não sei o que tempo real significa nesse contexto, mas provavelmente não, tempo real não parece caber aí.

Answer (score 5):

> Se eu quiser criar um app no Xamarin para Ios, sou obrigado a ter um Mac?

Você obrigatoriamente precisa do mac, seja ele físico ou um cloud. Isso porque a compilação do Xamarin.iOs é Ahead of Time (AOT) e há uma restrição de segurança no iOS, definida pela Apple, que não permite a execução de código gerado dinamicamente em um dispositivo.

> O Xamarin cria uma pasta no projeto Android e Ios, e qual seria a pasta pra Windows Phone?

Isso depende de qual versão do windows você selecionar no seu projeto. Ele pode gerar seuprojeto.UWP , seuprojeto.Windows e seuprojeto.Winphone. Que nada mais são do que as versões UWP , 8.* e windows phone.

> Xamarin cria o código nativo das demais plataformas em tempo real?

Se você quer dizer que o Xamarin.droid converte seu código c# em Android e que o Xamarin.iOs converte c# em swift , não. O Xamarin é nativo, leia esse trecho retirado do próprio site da xamarin (nesse caso falando de android):

> Os aplicativos Xamarin.Android são executados dentro do ambiente de execução Mono. Esse ambiente de execução é executado lado a lado com a máquina virtual Android Runtime (ART). Ambos os ambientes de tempo de execução funcionam em cima do kernel do Linux e expõem várias APIs ao código de usuário que permite que os desenvolvedores acessem o sistema subjacente. O tempo de execução Mono é escrito na linguagem C.

[Xamarin.droid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/)

[Xamarin.iOs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/architecture/)

Answer (score 2):

- Se eu quiser criar um app no Xamarin para Ios, sou obrigado a ter um Mac?
  -- não, hoje em dia vc pode contratar um serviço cloud para buildar sua app, caso não queira pagar pelo serviço sim, ai vc vai ter que ter um mac.
- O Xamarin cria uma pasta no projeto Android e Ios, e qual seria a pasta pra Windows Phone?
  -- Qual IDE vc está usando, VS? se for, tiver instalado o SDK do WP, vc irá identificar a pasta UWP, que nela sim terá o projeto do Universal App Windows.
  -- Se vc estiver no Mac e usando o Xamarin Studio, ai sim, só irá realmente ter as opções do iOS, e Android
- Xamarin cria o código nativo das demais plataformas em tempo real?
  -- Acredito que assim que compila a aplicação... realmente teria que definir o que seria tempo real pra vc.

Comment: Oi, então, qual seria a melhor solução para criar um app pra win, ios e android, visto que no windows nao gera pra ios e que no mac não gera pra windows phone?

Comment: Onde encontro esses serviços de Cloud?

Comment: Uma maquina com o mac, que vc possa virtualizar um Windows, dai vc colocaria no windows inicialmente para desenvolver, e quando fosse buildar o ios faria isso no ios.