# Como emular o iOS? Para testar aplicativos

Tags: java, android

Olá

Estou precisando desenvolver um aplicativo que rode no android e no iOS.
Estou pensando em utilizar o React Native. Me falaram do Flutter mas estou com medo por ter pouco tempo.

Então pensei.... como vou testar o aplicativo no iOS se não tenho um Mac.

Fiz uma procura rápida no google só vi pelo que entendi... que coloca o windows com a cara do iOS.

Tem hoje emuladores para Windows? Quais?

Comment: Flutter é Google, linguagem nova, para Android e iOS, e em breve Web... não tem como ficar com medo! Teria medo de perder o avanço no começo, isso sim!

Comment: Windows com cara de iOS não é emulador, é no máximo simulador e nem é capaz de rodar apps, nem de desenvolvimento, e não, Flutter **não é apenas uma linguagem**, é um KIt de desenvolvimento. A unica maneira de emular iOS é tendo um MacOS, ou criar um hackintosh ou contratar um cloud (servidor mac na nuvem).

Comment: Alguma responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213185/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157445/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é algo do Flutter em si, mas sim exigência da própria Apple, para compilar para iOS é necessário o Xcode, que só possui nos produtos dela mesmo, nem um pouco '**developer friendly**'.

Independente da tecnologia que você for utilizar(Flutter, React Native, Ionic, Nativo...), vai se deparar com este mesmo problema se quiser gerar app para iOS.

Mas isso não significa que você necessariamente precisa comprar um Mac. Você tem algumas opções:

- Pagar algumas horas para utilização de um Mac na nuvem. Serviços como [esse](https://www.macincloud.com/), [esse](https://xcloud.me/) ou [esse](http://maccloud.me/).
- Tentar instalar e usar o Mac no Windows através do VirtualBox, mas já aviso que é um caminho que irá dar muitos problemas. (mais [aqui](https://canaltech.com.br/macos/instale-o-os-x-mountain-lion-no-seu-computador-com-windows-usando-o-virtualbox/) ou [aqui](http://shiftaulasyt.blogspot.com/2018/01/como-instalar-o-mac-os-x-high-sierra-na.html))
- Pedir emprestado um Mac pra algum conhecido, ou pagar pelo empréstimo..

Mas além de tudo isso, é válido citar o seguinte.

O SDK do Flutter toma para si mesmo a responsabilidade de renderização de todos os widgets no canvas do nosso smartphone, o que significa que ele não 'depende' de plataforma para esse serviço, o que acaba dando uma liberdade imensa para os desenvolvedores e independência visual da plataforma em si.

Tendo isso em mente, para você saber como o seu app vai ficar no iOS (visualmente e comportavelmente), bastaria '**enganar**' o SDK para ele achar que está rodando em um iOS. E para nossa alegria, para fazer isso com o Flutter bastaria o clique de um botão.

Utilizando o próprio flutter inspector, existe essa opção *Togge platform*:

[image: Toggle Platform]

Após clicar, no console sai a informação:

`Switched platform rendering to Android.`

ou

`Switched platform rendering to iOS.`

E o comportamento do app rodando com Android 'imita' o comportamento do app com iOS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima, o título da AppBar renderiza ao centro caso for iOS.

Comment: Cara... você esta puxando pro lado do Flutter... não pode ser... rsrs... Show... vou ter que testar essa parada.

Comment: React Native pode ser uma boa opção também. O [Expo](expo.io) oferece uma excelente abstração pra isso e permite que você teste em dispositivos reais sem precisar compilar o código nativo (seja para iPhone ou Android).

Comment: Mathias... mas esse expo... eu consigo carregar meu projeto? Como funciona